# Could we use permutation polynomials for Shamir's secret sharing scheme?

Tags: secret-sharing, group-theory, permutation

Could we use [permutation polynomials](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0509523.pdf) for secret sharing scheme like Shamir's? The say that they induce a bijection over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ what does this mean and how does it helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **No**

A permutation polynomial is a polynomial $f:\mathbb{Z}_p\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_p$ which is a bijection meaning
the list $[f(x): x \in \mathbb{Z}_p]$ is a permutation of the elements of the field.

*Example:* For example $f(x)=x^3$ gives the list $[0,1,3,2,4]$ as $x$ ranges over $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

But these polynomials *leak* information since if you know  $(x_0,f(x_0))$ you know for all $x\neq x_0$ the value of $f$ is different than $f(x_0)$.

This means that the Shamir argument about the polynomial values being uniformly distributed if some $s$ shares for $<s<t$ are known no longer holds. Here $t$ is the threshold.

So, no need to do this it introduces a weakness.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: In short, it is no more perfect secrecy.